# Putting notes to the side

Tags: positioning, footnotes

Is there a package to put "footnotes" to the side like in this example : http://www.bvh.univ-tours.fr/Consult/consult.asp?numfiche=571&index=15&numtable=B372615206_18229&mode=1&ecran=0 ?

Comment: Do you want the two-column layout as well or just the footnotes in the margin?

Comment: I'd like to get as close as possible to this layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `footmisc` package does this with its `side` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[side]{footmisc}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}% adjust to your document's needs

\begin{document}

Hello\footnote{This is some text in the margin that should break and everything.}
World\footnote{And some more text that should go to the margin as well and behave like
the other footnote.}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to put some on the left, too?

Comment: I just tried `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`, which put the left column's footnotes in the left margin and the right column's in the right margin. In your example, however, the margins seem to be treated almost like another two columns, just starting left and continuing right. No idea how to do this.

Comment: `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` doesn't work in TL2009 (I'll try in TL2011 later).