# Is it possible to have tufte-like citations in a general documentclass?

Tags: bibliographies, margins, marginpar, tufte, marginnote

The `tufte` packages/class is very nice. But (opinion based) it is too invasive for simple documents. I want to selectively use some features in a normal `article` class.

Is is possible to have tufte-like citations in it? (note I don't mind increasing the right margin, as it is necessary to have the space)

Here it is an example: [image: tuftebiblio]

Here is a MWE (used `bibitem` to make the example clear, but other methods are ok too):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Using the MASCOT representation \cite{mascot}.

\begin{thebibliography}{6}
\bibitem{mascot} H R Simpson and K Jackson, {\em Process Synchronisation
in MASCOT}, The Computer Journal, {\bf 22}, 332, 1979
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @DG' thanks, but will it work without changing the `\cite` command?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to have tufte-like citations in a general `documentclass`.

[image: Citations in sidenotes]

What you need is (1) a citation style that uses footnotes, and (2) a mechanism that places footnotes in the margin. Amongst others you can use `biblatex` or `bibtex` for (1) and `snotez`, `sidenotes`, as well as built in commands in `memoir` and `KOMA-script`. I will provide some examples/possible combinations below:

You can either use  [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf) and [`snotez`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/snotez/snotez_en.pdf):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[outer=7cm,marginparwidth=5cm]{geometry} % setting large outer margin
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[footnote=true]{snotez}                  % footnotes as sidenotes

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{somebody-sgt,
      ids       =   {someone-sgt},
      author    =   {Somebody, Someone},
      title     =   {Some Great Title},
      journal   =   {Best Journal},
      year      =   3019,
      pages     =   {32--39},
      volume    =   3,
      number    =   4}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\let\cite=\autocite                                % force \autocite  

\begin{document}

Using the MASCOT representation \cite{somebody-sgt}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Or  [`biblatex`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf) and [`sidenotes`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/sidenotes/sidenotes.pdf) (which also provides other `tufte`-like structures, e.g. marginfigures and -tables):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[outer=7cm,marginparwidth=5cm]{geometry} % setting large outer margin
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{sidenotes}
\let\footnote=\sidenote                             % footnotes as sidenotes

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{somebody-sgt,
      ids       =   {someone-sgt},
      author    =   {Somebody, Someone},
      title     =   {Some Great Title},
      journal   =   {Best Journal},
      year      =   3019,
      pages     =   {32--39},
      volume    =   3,
      number    =   4}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\let\cite=\autocite                                 % force \autocite

\begin{document}

Using the MASCOT representation \cite{somebody-sgt}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

It is possible to achieve the same result with `bibtex` (or `natbib`), given, that a style with footnotes is used. [`opcit`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/opcit/opcit.pdf), for example, is such a style:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[outer=7cm,marginparwidth=5cm]{geometry} % setting large outer margin
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{opcit}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\let\footnote=\sidenote                             % footnotes as sidenotes

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @article{somebody-sgt,
      ids       =   {someone-sgt},
      author    =   {Somebody, Someone},
      title     =   {Some Great Title},
      journal   =   {Best Journal},
      year      =   3019,
      pages     =   {32--39},
      volume    =   3,
      number    =   4}
\end{filecontents}

%\let\cite=\autocite                                 % force \autocite

\begin{document}

Using the MASCOT representation \cite{somebody-sgt}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, to confirm, this needs to switch to `biblatex`.

Comment: You need to switch to a format, that uses `\footnote`. Do you want/need to use `thebibliography` and `\bibitem`?

Comment: not necessarely. I wanted to have an idea on the dependencies of this. I had problems adapting to biblatex in the past, but I will give it another try. So basically, `biblatex` comes with an `autocite` command that works with footnotes?

Comment: Basically: yes. The easy solution would be to use `biblatex` and `\autocite`. But you can also use `bibtex` or `natbib`  with any style that uses footnotes or put citations manually in footnotes.

Comment: @alfC Added solution using `bibtex`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like:

```
\documentclass[twoside,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[side,ragged]{footmisc}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, autocite=footnote, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.5cm} % just to add some space to margin note
\usepackage{marginfix} % to avoid problems at the end of the page with margin notes
```

See also: [Putting notes to the side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24390/putting-notes-to-the-side)

%% From DC's answer:%%

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{somebody-sgt,
  ids       =   {someone-sgt},
  author    =   {Somebody, Someone},
  title     =   {Some Great Title},
  journal   =   {Best Journal},
  year      =   3019,
  pages     =   {32--39},
  volume    =   3,
  number    =   4}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\let\cite=\autocite                                 % force \autocite

\begin{document}

Using the MASCOT representation \cite{somebody-sgt}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

No need for packages `opcit`, `snotez` or `sidenotes` -- though the latter might be useful for other purposes.