# How can one simultaneously put footnotes to the side and have multiple columns of text?

Tags: fancyhdr, multicol, footmisc

`multicol` allows multiple columns with `\begin{multicols}[n]`. `footmisc` with the  option `side` allows footnotes to be placed on the side of a page, with width specified by `\marginparwidth`. Their combination, even with their most basic use cases, seems not to work.

An example, from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24390/putting-notes-to-the-side), exhibits the behaviour above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[side]{footmisc}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}% adjust to your document's needs

\begin{document}

Hello\footnote{This is some text in the margin that should break and everything.}
World\footnote{And some more text that should go to the margin as well and behave like
the other footnote.}.

\end{document}
```

Above, the footnotes are displayed. Below, they aren't. (Nor are the columns, though that is because there're only two words, and not because of some other problem)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[side]{footmisc}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}% adjust to your document's needs

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

Hello\footnote{This is some text in the margin that should break and everything.}
World\footnote{And some more text that should go to the margin as well and behave like
the other footnote.}.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

A final request is that any solution ensures that `fancyhdr` headers and footers are spread out as they would be. I have seen some solutions where footnotes are put in expanded margins, but `fancyhdr` seems to then make the headers and footers narrower.

Comment: According to the manual (page 2) floats and \marginpar are not allowed inside the multicol environment (were never implemented).

Comment: \marginnote works, but will overlap istself.

Comment: If you don't mind getting a page break when you change from one column to two columns or back, you can use \twocolumn and \onecolumn.

Comment: Thanks for the information, @JohnKormylo; a quick clarification - what do you mean by overlapping in `\marginpar`?

Comment: \marginnote overlaps.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment or use `\let\marginpar=\marginnote` (after loading the marginnote package),